# make entire match fail if conditions not met

Tags: regex, r

I am testing out backtracking and match failures with the use of alternation.

Say I have the following regular expression:

```
(foobar|barbaz)
```

And I run this on a vector of the following strings.

```
x <- c('In context I have foobar and barbaz', 'In context I have foobaz and barbaz', 'In context I have fooquz and barbaz')
regmatches(x, gregexpr('(foobar|barbaz)', x))
# [[1]]
# [1] "foobar" "barbaz"

# [[2]]
# [1] "barbaz"

# [[3]]
# [1] "barbaz"
```

Is there a way to make a match completely fail returning no results?

For example, in the regex `(foobar|barbaz)` is there a way to make the entire match fail completely if the left side expression only matches up until `foo` but fail if there is no `b` after foo? Meaning the right side expression would not even be looked at or matched.

So in this case the third string would completely fail because there is no `b` after `foo` in `fooquz` therefore it should not try the right side expression and the entire match would fail returning no results at all?

Comment: Right now, `(foobar|barbaz)` means match "foobar" or match "barbaz". Do you mean you want instead to match "foobar" followed by "barbaz"?

Comment: No, i would like to match both except if foo is not follwed by the letter b, then it would not even backtrack to the right expression and cause the entire match to fail.

Comment: I think he wants the last two strings to have 0 matches. He wants to match barbaz only if foobar has a match.

Comment: I assume he wants the third vector result to completely fail and not try the right side expression because foo is preceded by the letter `q` and not `b`

Comment: Yes is foo is not followed by a b then fail entire match otherwise match both or the one that matches

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're not familiar with ([`PCRE`](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt)) it will benefit you to read the documentation before advancing. You can switch on [`PCRE`](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt) by using `perl = TRUE` and use backtracking verbs for this.

```
> x <- c('foobar and barbaz', 'foobaz and barbaz', 'fooquz and barbaz')
> regmatches(x, gregexpr('(foo(*COMMIT)b(*THEN)ar|barbaz)', x, perl=T))
## [[1]]
## [1] "foobar" "barbaz"

## [[2]]
## [1] "barbaz"

## [[3]]
## character(0)
```

To clearly see that the third vector element completely fails, filter the results.

```
> Filter(length, 
         regmatches(x, gregexpr('(foo(*COMMIT)b(*THEN)ar|barbaz)', x, perl=T)))
## [[1]]
## [1] "foobar" "barbaz"

## [[2]]
## [1] "barbaz"
```

**Explanation**:

- `(*COMMIT)` causes overall failure, no advance of starting point.
- `(*THEN)` causes a skip to the next innermost alternative when back-tracking reaches it.
- If `foo` matches but `b` fails the backtrack to `(*COMMIT)` causes the entire match to fail.
- If `foo` and `b` match, but `ar` fails, the backtrack to `(*THEN)` causes the next alternative `barbaz` to be tried.

Answer (score 0):

Yes to do that you can use the `(*COMMIT)` backtracking control verb:

```
(?:foo(*COMMIT)bar|barbaz)
```

This verb will cause the entire pattern fail if the pattern after it fails.